# Data doesnt save into database

Tags: c#, database

i am working on a program to my work and I cant find out how to save properly to the database. I have tried everything that i thought it could be a problem, but nothing works. I have some XAML UI which is very long code so i wont place it here. My issue is that I am saving into this database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[checklist] (
[Id]            INT        IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[tb_00]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_01]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_02]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_03]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_04]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[dp_00]         DATE       NULL,
[cb_A0]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A1]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A2]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A3]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A4]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A5]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A6]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A7]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A8]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A9]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A10]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A11]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A12]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A13]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A14]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A15]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A16]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A17]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A18]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A19]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A20]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A21]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A22]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A23]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A24]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A25]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A26]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A27]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A28]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A29]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A30]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A31]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A32]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A33]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A34]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A35]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A36]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A37]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A38]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A39]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A40]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A41]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_A42]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B0]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B1]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B2]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B3]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B4]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B5]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B6]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B7]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B8]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B9]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B10]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B11]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B12]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B13]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B14]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B15]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B16]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B17]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B18]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B19]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B20]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B21]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B22]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B23]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B24]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B25]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B26]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B27]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B28]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B29]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B30]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B31]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B32]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B33]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B34]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B35]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B36]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B37]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B38]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[cb_B39]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[canvas_podpis] IMAGE      NULL,
[tb_C0]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_C1]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_C2]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_C3]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_C4]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_C5]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_C6]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_C7]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_C8]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_C9]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_C10]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_C11]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_D0]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_D1]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_D2]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_D3]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_D4]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_D5]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_D6]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_D7]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_D8]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_D9]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_D10]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_D11]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_D12]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_D13]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_D14]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_D15]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_D16]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_E0]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_E1]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_E2]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_E3]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_E4]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_E5]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_E6]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_E7]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_E8]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_E9]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_E10]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_E11]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_E12]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_E13]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_E14]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_E15]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_E16]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_E17]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_E18]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_E19]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_E20]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_E21]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_E22]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_E23]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_F0]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_F1]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_F2]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_F3]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_F4]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_F5]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_F6]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_F7]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_F8]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_F9]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_F10]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_F11]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_G0]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_G1]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_G2]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_G3]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_G4]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_G5]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_G6]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_G7]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_G8]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_G9]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_G10]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_G11]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_H0]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_H1]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_H2]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_H3]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_H4]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_H5]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_H6]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_H7]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_H8]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_H9]         NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_H10]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_H11]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[tb_pozn]       NCHAR (10) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC));
```

using this:

```
 private void Uloz()
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=""|DataDirectory|\zldb.mdf"";Integrated Security=True");
        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            string sqlquery = "insert into checklist (tb_00,tb_01,tb_02,tb_03,tb_04,dp_00,cb_A0,cb_A1,cb_A2,cb_A3,cb_A4,cb_A5,cb_A6,cb_A7,cb_A8,cb_A9,cb_A10,cb_A11,cb_A12,cb_A13,cb_A14,cb_A15,cb_A16,cb_A17,cb_A18,cb_A19,cb_A20,cb_A21,cb_A22,cb_A23,cb_A24,cb_A25,cb_A26,cb_A27,cb_A28,cb_A29,cb_A30,cb_A31,cb_A32,cb_A33,cb_A34,cb_A35,cb_A36,cb_A37,cb_A38,cb_A39,cb_A40,cb_A41,cb_A42,cb_B0,cb_B1,cb_B2,cb_B3,cb_B4,cb_B5,cb_B6,cb_B7,cb_B8,cb_B9,cb_B10,cb_B11,cb_B12,cb_B13,cb_B14,cb_B15,cb_B16,cb_B17,cb_B18,cb_B19,cb_B20,cb_B21,cb_B22,cb_B23,cb_B24,cb_B25,cb_B26,cb_B27,cb_B28,cb_B29,cb_B30,cb_B31,cb_B32,cb_B33,cb_B34,cb_B35,cb_B36,cb_B37,cb_B38,cb_B39,canvas_podpis,tb_C0,tb_C1,tb_C2,tb_C3,tb_C4,tb_C5,tb_C6,tb_C7,tb_C8,tb_C9,tb_C10,tb_C11,tb_D0,tb_D1,tb_D2,tb_D3,tb_D4,tb_D5,tb_D6,tb_D7,tb_D8,tb_D9,tb_D10,tb_D11,tb_D12,tb_D13,tb_D14,tb_D15,tb_D16,tb_E0,tb_E1,tb_E2,tb_E3,tb_E4,tb_E5,tb_E6,tb_E7,tb_E8,tb_E9,tb_E10,tb_E11,tb_E12,tb_E13,tb_E14,tb_E15,tb_E16,tb_E17,tb_E18,tb_E19,tb_E20,tb_E21,tb_E22,tb_E23,tb_F0,tb_F1,tb_F2,tb_F3,tb_F4,tb_F5,tb_F6,tb_F7,tb_F8,tb_F9,tb_F10,tb_F11,tb_G0,tb_G1,tb_G2,tb_G3,tb_G4,tb_G5,tb_G6,tb_G7,tb_G8,tb_G9,tb_G10,tb_G11,tb_H0,tb_H1,tb_H2,tb_H3,tb_H4,tb_H5,tb_H6,tb_H7,tb_H8,tb_H9,tb_H10,tb_H11,tb_pozn) VALUES ('" + tb_00.Text + "','" + tb_01.Text + "','" + tb_02.Text + "','" + tb_03.Text + "','" + tb_04.Text + "','" + dp_00.SelectedDate + "','" + cb_A0.Text + "','" + cb_A1.Text + "','" + cb_A2.Text + "','" + cb_A3.Text + "','" + cb_A4.Text + "','" + cb_A5.Text + "','" + cb_A6.Text + "','" + cb_A7.Text + "','" + cb_A8.Text + "','" + cb_A9.Text + "','" + cb_A10.Text + "','" + cb_A11.Text + "','" + cb_A12.Text + "','" + cb_A13.Text + "','" + cb_A14.Text + "','" + cb_A15.Text + "','" + cb_A16.Text + "','" + cb_A17.Text + "','" + cb_A18.Text + "','" + cb_A19.Text + "','" + cb_A20.Text + "','" + cb_A21.Text + "','" + cb_A22.Text + "','" + cb_A23.Text + "','" + cb_A24.Text + "','" + cb_A25.Text + "','" + cb_A26.Text + "','" + cb_A27.Text + "','" + cb_A28.Text + "','" + cb_A29.Text + "','" + cb_A30.Text + "','" + cb_A31.Text + "','" + cb_A32.Text + "','" + cb_A33.Text + "','" + cb_A34.Text + "','" + cb_A35.Text + "','" + cb_A36.Text + "','" + cb_A37.Text + "','" + cb_A38.Text + "','" + cb_A39.Text + "','" + cb_A40.Text + "','" + cb_A41.Text + "','" + cb_A42.Text + "','" + cb_B0.Text + "','" + cb_B1.Text + "','" + cb_B2.Text + "','" + cb_B3.Text + "','" + cb_B4.Text + "','" + cb_B5.Text + "','" + cb_B6.Text + "','" + cb_B7.Text + "','" + cb_B8.Text + "','" + cb_B9.Text + "','" + cb_B10.Text + "','" + cb_B11.Text + "','" + cb_B12.Text + "','" + cb_B13.Text + "','" + cb_B14.Text + "','" + cb_B15.Text + "','" + cb_B16.Text + "','" + cb_B17.Text + "','" + cb_B18.Text + "','" + cb_B19.Text + "','" + cb_B20.Text + "','" + cb_B21.Text + "','" + cb_B22.Text + "','" + cb_B23.Text + "','" + cb_B24.Text + "','" + cb_B25.Text + "','" + cb_B26.Text + "','" + cb_B27.Text + "','" + cb_B28.Text + "','" + cb_B29.Text + "','" + cb_B30.Text + "','" + cb_B31.Text + "','" + cb_B32.Text + "','" + cb_B33.Text + "','" + cb_B34.Text + "','" + cb_B35.Text + "','" + cb_B36.Text + "','" + cb_B37.Text + "','" + cb_B38.Text + "','" + cb_B39.Text + "', @podpis_mech ,'" + tb_C0.Text + "','" + tb_C1.Text + "','" + tb_C2.Text + "','" + tb_C3.Text + "','" + tb_C4.Text + "','" + tb_C5.Text + "','" + tb_C6.Text + "','" + tb_C7.Text + "','" + tb_C8.Text + "','" + tb_C9.Text + "','" + tb_C10.Text + "','" + tb_C11.Text + "','" + tb_D0.Text + "','" + tb_D1.Text + "','" + tb_D2.Text + "','" + tb_D3.Text + "','" + tb_D4.Text + "','" + tb_D5.Text + "','" + tb_D6.Text + "','" + tb_D7.Text + "','" + tb_D8.Text + "','" + tb_D9.Text + "','" + tb_D10.Text + "','" + tb_D11.Text + "','" + tb_D12.Text + "','" + tb_D13.Text + "','" + tb_D14.Text + "','" + tb_D15.Text + "','" + tb_D16.Text + "','" + tb_E0.Text + "','" + tb_E1.Text + "','" + tb_E2.Text + "','" + tb_E3.Text + "','" + tb_E4.Text + "','" + tb_E5.Text + "','" + tb_E6.Text + "','" + tb_E7.Text + "','" + tb_E8.Text + "','" + tb_E9.Text + "','" + tb_E10.Text + "','" + tb_E11.Text + "','" + tb_E12.Text + "','" + tb_E13.Text + "','" + tb_E14.Text + "','" + tb_E15.Text + "','" + tb_E16.Text + "','" + tb_E17.Text + "','" + tb_E18.Text + "','" + tb_E19.Text + "','" + tb_E20.Text + "','" + tb_E21.Text + "','" + tb_E22.Text + "','" + tb_E23.Text + "','" + tb_F0.Text + "','" + tb_F1.Text + "','" + tb_F2.Text + "','" + tb_F3.Text + "','" + tb_F4.Text + "','" + tb_F5.Text + "','" + tb_F6.Text + "','" + tb_F7.Text + "','" + tb_F8.Text + "','" + tb_F9.Text + "','" + tb_F10.Text + "','" + tb_F11.Text + "','" + tb_G0.Text + "','" + tb_G1.Text + "','" + tb_G2.Text + "','" + tb_G3.Text + "','" + tb_G4.Text + "','" + tb_G5.Text + "','" + tb_G6.Text + "','" + tb_G7.Text + "','" + tb_G8.Text + "','" + tb_G9.Text + "','" + tb_G10.Text + "','" + tb_G11.Text + "','" + tb_H0.Text + "','" + tb_H1.Text + "','" + tb_H2.Text + "','" + tb_H3.Text + "','" + tb_H4.Text + "','" + tb_H5.Text + "','" + tb_H6.Text + "','" + tb_H7.Text + "','" + tb_H8.Text + "','" + tb_H9.Text + "','" + tb_H10.Text + "','" + tb_H11.Text + "','" + tb_pozn.Text + "');";
            string SqlDataPull = sqlquery;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlDataPull, myConnection);

            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@podpis_mech", GlobalZL.podpis_mech);

        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

When i look into the data of database there is only one line full of NULL.
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You should use parametized queries instead of string concatenation, your program is asking for an SQL injection. Without your code is impossible to tell, provide full method code.

Comment: Remove the try/catch and check the exceptions raised. That `catch{}` means you'll never know what caused the command to fail

Comment: BTW that query doesn't have any parameters. Why pass `@popdis_mech`? If one parameter is used, why not pass *all* strings as parameters?

Comment: Get familiar with a logging framework like NLog
 and then use it in `catch`

Comment: @popdis_mech is an image so I tried to save it like that

Comment: You aren't saving it anywhere in that string. Besides, why store only that in the proper way, why not treat every value properly? Parameters aren't optional. Imagine [what would happen](https://xkcd.com/327/) if the last combobox contained `'; drop table users;--`. That's what SQL injection looks like. Do follow the link

Comment: I tried to remove catch{} and it didnt fire any exception

Comment: You're not executing the command.  Add `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` after all the other code in the `try` block.

Comment: As for the query itself, if all combox are emtpy the table will get a row whose fields have 10-char long values full of empty spaces, not NULLs

Comment: Ok, so how should i save that image if my colleague want @podpis_mech saved as an image

Comment: Given the unused parameter, the NULLs that just can't be there and the fact *this* query isn't executed, I suspect your code runs a *different* query, not this one

Comment: @KláraOborná read the previous comment. You aren't even executing *this* query. Whatever produced the NULLs is another query

Comment: Ok I added cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); and it still doesnt save still full of NULLs. I usualy dont use database so i am a bit lost here

Comment: This is pretty hard to read. Do us and yourself a favor and set up a small experiment with 1 or 2 columns. See [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code below with following changes:

1. Using block to ensure SQL connection is disposed of after usage
2. User input is passed as parameters to prevent Sql Injection
3. Remove empty catch block because it was swallowing any error thrown
4. Added cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); to execute the query, which should insert your row in DB

P.S. I have also removed extra columns to make this readable

```
     private void Uloz()
        {
            using(SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=""|DataDirectory|\zldb.mdf"";Integrated Security=True")){
                myConnection.Open();
                string sqlquery = @"insert into checklist (tb_00,tb_01) 
VALUES (@tb_00, @tb_01);";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery , myConnection);    
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@podpis_mech", GlobalZL.podpis_mech);

//edit
//Pass parameters with explicit DB types
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tb_00", SqlDbType.NChar, 10) {Value = tb_00.Text});
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tb_01", SqlDbType.NChar, 10) {Value = tb_01.Text});
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Comment: When i use cmd.ExecuteNonQuery It throw exception that says cannost use with nvarchar

Comment: Also I have tried to edit it like you and the same problem data didnt show only ton of NULLs.

Comment: @KláraOborná By default in c# strings are passed as NVarchar. just edited my answer to pass values as NChar explicitly.

Comment: @KláraOborná also you need to pass your dates with `SqlDbType.Date`